# Calling Self Executing Function from A Different JS File

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've read about Self Executing Function in JavaScript and decided to give it a try today. I ran into an issue that I have not been able to fix.

**I have a file call service.js**

```
var api = (function (window, document, $, undefined) {

var Service = function (obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}
 window.Service = Service

return {
    service : Service
}
```

})(window, document, jQuery);

**I have another file call CallServiceAPI.js**

```
$('#SearchUser').on('click', function () {
    var SearchUserObj = {}
    //Build an object with the necessary properties and try to call the api

    var FindUser = api.Service(SearchUserObj)
});
```

It's throwing the following error:
Reference.js:41 Uncaught ReferenceError: api is not defined.

What did I do wrong?

After reading the comments, I think I totally misunderstood [this](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) article.

Comment: Your self executing function doesn't return anything so `api` remains undefined. (This doesn't have anything to do with the code being in two separate files.)

Comment: @Juhana, I am a little confused then. I was returning something, and I had the same problem. After reading your comment, I updated the code. I am still getting the same exception.

Comment: ... + `window.Service` is also `undefined`, declarations are hoisted, assignments are not. After your edit, there's still no `Service` function defined in `api` (JS is case-sensitive).

Comment: As mentioned in some of the comments, you have not declared 'service'. If you replace the lowercase 'service' with 'Service' and reference both files in your page or the file that is using them, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments, I was able to fix it by:
1. Make sure all variables are declared properly
2. Reference the file in my layout

```
var api = (function (window, document, $, undefined) {

var Service = function (obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}
 window.Service = Service

return {
    Service : Service
}
```